# JavaScript adding quotes to output

Tags: javascript, html

Here my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
  <html> 
    <body>     
      <h2>JavaScript Operators</h2>

      <p>The + operator concatenates (adds) strings.</p>

      <p id="demo"></p>
    </body> 

    <script> 
      var txt1 = '"Jhon"'; 
      var txt2 = "Doe";
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt1 + " " + txt2;
    </script>
  </html>
```

The output would be like Jhon Doe but I want to add quote to the output like "Jhon" "Doe". I know I can do this by adding escape to variable like "Jhon"' or "\"Jhon\"" but my variable isn't string in my actual code, this is just an example.

Just trying to make it clear again, I cannot edit string variable value I want to edit the output somewhere here to add the quotes

> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt1 + " " + txt2;

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "\"" + txt1 + " " + txt2 + "\"";`

Comment: i mean... your demo code shows you how to use string concatenation. Why can't you use string concatenation? That's likely what the assignment expects you do anyway.

Comment: +1 to what @KevinB suggested. Can't you simply concat the escape character for quotes on either side of the variable. What do you mean when you say it isn't a string in your actual code?

Comment: String template literal would make this look nicer. `\`"${txt1}" "${txt2}"\``

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. you're missing two quotes.

Comment: There is a <q> tag, fyi: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q

Comment: Off-topic: For anyone like me who wrongly assumed that "Jhon" was a typo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jhon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can double-stringify string variable with JSON.stringify, if I understood you correctly:

```js
var txt1 = "Jhon";
var txt2 = "Doe";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(txt1) + " " + JSON.stringify(txt2);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: This is not the intended use of JSON stringify, if all you need to do is add quotes, I strongly recommend you just add quotes as you concatenate

Comment: @Ben It's not always possible to add quotes when string comes say from external source. In addition you don't know what type of quotes it might have. So yes – this is exactly intended use of stringification.

Comment: @dsfq On the contrary, it is always possible to add quotes, either with concatenation or string splitting, however, it is not always possible with stringify, and the intended use for stringify is making a valid JSON Object String, which happens to, on non-objects and arrays, enclose them in double quotes. It is not a good idea to do it this way, and I suspect performance will also be much worse

Answer (score 0):

Since the accepted answer uses `JSON.stringify()` in an inefficient and unintended way, that has worse browser support, not to mention it is unintuitive and odd, I thought I would do it the normal and theoretically faster way.

KEEP IN MIND, the accepted answer is fine for the listed purposes, I simply think it better to do things the intuitive way, you want to add quotes, this is how you add quotes. `JSON.stringify()` is for creating a JSON string of a variable or object, which happens to add quotes.

Change your text output to look like this:

`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '"'+txt1+'"' + " " + '"'+txt2+'"';`

You can also use the `\"` escape sequence if you so desire.

This is more versatile in quite a few ways, as you can now do things like this:

```
var quote="\"";
var names=[
    ["John", "Doe"],
    ["Jane", "Doe"],
    ["Jennifer", "Dawn"]
];
names.forEach(function(item,key){
    var txt1=item[0];
    var txt2=item[1];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += quote+txt1+quote + " " + quote+txt2+quote+"<br/>";
});
```

Where `quote="\""`

Expected output

```
"John" "Doe"
"Jane" "Doe"
"Jennifer" "Dawn"
```

Where `quote="'"`

Expected output

```
'John' 'Doe'
'Jane' 'Doe'
'Jennifer' 'Dawn'
```

Etc etc. This makes complex string manipulation much easier, especially when it comes to prices and putting the correct currency symbol.